# JavaFX Find index values of items currently in view

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I am working on a project in JavaFX 2 and I am using a ListView to display a list of messages. The list is very long and so not all of it fits on screen. Is there any way to programmatically identify which items are currently in the view? I've searched everywhere online and I can't find any examples of a way to do this, nor does the API appear to have any notion of which items are on screen. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been working on this problem for quite some time.

Comment: The API has no way to do this. Can you explain why you think you need it?

Comment: I guess I should say the API has no *direct* way to do this. There are some hacks, but you probably don't need to do this anyway.

Comment: I've wanted to do this for a long time as well.  I can confirm there is no such API.  Oh, and why I needed it?  I wanted to be able to navigate to a different  screen, and later restore the screen exactly as it was (including having list items in the exact same position, with the same selection).

Comment: @john16384 Why would navigating to another screen cause the list view to change its state?

Comment: It was saving the position of where you were when navigating (like in a browser, when you press back, you get the same position in the page -- if it is a half decent browser).  I cannot keep those views around just in case someone navigates back to it...

Comment: @john16384 I would keep the views, unless I had real evidence doing so caused a problem.

Comment: @john16384 Also, for that particular use case, you can do `double scrollValue = ((ScrollBar) listView.lookup(".scroll-bar:vertical")).getValue();` when you navigate away... Though I would still probably just keep the views.

Comment: Thanks, I'll test that... if I could keep the views, I would, but that's not feasible.

Comment: @James_D I was afraid of that. The messages I am listing are of varying types, and one of those types is a time stamp that identifies the time at which some number of the following messages occurred. What I am trying to do is identify when one of those time stamps is being scrolled off the top of the screen and grab the information from it to use somewhere else.